# Apache 2.4 in Windows Server 2008 is not loading php_intl extension

Tags: php, windows, apache

I have this infrastructure:

- PHP Version: 5.6.20
- System:  Windows NT SERVER1 6.1 build 7600 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Compiler:     MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
- Architecture     x64
- Loaded Configuration: File   C:\php\php.ini

Other tools:

- Visual C++ Redistributable para Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 installed
- Apache and PHP were installed individually

The extension **php_intl.dll** is never loaded, just this one. Others extensions are loaded cool. When I restart the apache I get this warning:

> [Wed Jul 06 14:41:03.632426 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14964:tid 356] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 14992
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

The extension is there, so the ext's path is ok. Finally I went to [Intl Pecl dowloadpage](https://pecl.php.net/package/intl) and looks like the repositories there are not compatible with Windows Server 2008.

I do not know what more to do in order to get this extension work.

> **Addional note**: I have copied the Apache24/ and php/ dir into a Windows 7 machine 64x and the extension is loaded successfully

Comment: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/unable-to-load-or-find-php-extension-php_intl-dll

Comment: Thank you Zak, but wamp server has not relation here (?)

Comment: I understand, however did you read the rest where it's explaining that you might not have the Virtual C++ library installed which is required by php_intl.dll

Comment: Yeah, indeed that library is required by Apache itself to get work

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to register the php instead php's extension path in Windows PATH enviroment variable.

```
C:\php
```

By this way the apache is able to load all `icud*.dll` files required by `php_intl.dll`.
*Credits by [@Vrac](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16070/apache-2-4-en-windows-server-2008-no-carga-la-extensi%c3%b3n-php-intl?noredirect=1#comment26476_16070)*

And and [@Zak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233782/apache-2-4-in-windows-server-2008-is-not-loading-php-intl-extension/38248236#comment63889420_38233782):

> Make sure the PHP directory path is included in the system’s PATH environmental variable so this set of provided/included ICU DLLs, that php_intl.dll depends on, are found